# Retrieve blob file from database with PDO

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to display images that are stored to the db using BLOB type. Anyway when I run my code I get no result. When I store the images to the DB I get no error and everything works great, but when I try to display them I get this:
[image not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcLhU.png)

I don't know if further code is required because I'm very new, so aks if you need something! Could the problem be the way I run my while loop? Using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` ?? Thanks in advance!

The way I store the images in the DB is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $preview=$_POST['preview'];
    $main=$_POST['main'];
    $created = $_POST['created'];
    
    $imageName=$_FILES['immagine']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['immagine']['type'];
    $file = $_FILES['immagine']['name'];

    $imageContent= addslashes(file_get_contents($imageName));
   
  //Query for Insertion
    $data = [
        'title' => $title,
        'category' => $category,
        'preview' => $preview,
        'main' => $main,
        'immagine' => $imageContent,
        'created' => $created,
        'type' => $type,
    ];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO post (title, category, preview, main, created, image, type) VALUES (:title, :category, :preview, :main, :created, :immagine, :type)";

    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute($data);
```

And the way I try to retrieve the images is this:
(There's a lot php that I use for other functions but the final query is this: `$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE` title `LIKE '%$search%' or 'category' LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");`)

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';

//Search box

$search = $_GET['query'];
$limit = 6;

//total number record

$countsql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM post");
$countsql->execute();
$row = $countsql->fetch();
$num_records = $row[0];
$num_links = ceil($num_records/$limit);
$page = $_GET['start'];

if (!isset($_GET['start'])) {
    $page = 1;
}
else{
    $page = $_GET['start'];
}

$start = ($page-1) * $limit;
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE `title` LIKE '%$search%' or 'category' LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
$stmt->execute();

?>
<html>
<div class="Elementi">
                <?php while($contacts = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                    ?>


                <div class="colonne">
                    <div class="Cards">
                        <a class="links" href="read.php?id=<?=$contacts->ID; ?>">
                            <div class="box_immagine">
                                <?php echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($contacts->image).'" alt="Immagine" class="immagine_post">'; ?>
                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="Categorie">
                                <p class="Testo_categorie"><?=$contacts->category?></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="testo_contenuto">
                                <p class="titolo_card"><?=$contacts->title; ?></p>
                                <textarea class="Testo_preview" readonly><?=$contacts->preview?></textarea>
                                <p class="altro">[READ]</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: `addslashes()` probably corrupted the file. Instead convert the binary image file to base64

Comment: should not store images in database, your code is also open to sql injection and stored XSS attacks

Comment: I know but I tried to follow the tutorial by heroku on how to use amazon s3 but it doesn't work https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-php @LawrenceCherone

Comment: you can store the files on filesystem, s3 is ideal but if you need load balancing there is better ways than storing in mysql

Comment: I used to do like you suggested but I'm using heroku and it have an ephemeral filesystem, so this system doesn't work. Everytime a Dyno is restarted I lose my images
https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: +1 for S3, -1 for mysql. Why not post a question about getting your S3 code to work instead? In general, if you're using prepared statements correctly, you should never need to use `(add|strip)slashes()` or additional layers of encoding like base64. Speaking of which, your search query is _ripe_ for injection. `$search='%'.$search.'%';` and then use `prepare()`.

Comment: @Sammitch I'm gonna try to make the script works and otherwise I'll post a question about it, thanks!